# Async deadlocks issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await, deadlock

My code goes into a deadlock when using `await client.GetAsync(url)` and `await SendParkInfoRequest(parkRegionId)`. It works fine if I use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Below is my code.

```
    public virtual async Task<ParkingInfo> SendParkInfoRequest(string id)
    {
        using (var client = Helper.GetHttpClient())
        {
                //
                var url = RequestUri + id;
                var data = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
                string result = await data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<AvailableSpotsResponse> GetAvailableSpots(string parkRegionId)
    {
        //
        var data = await SendParkInfoRequest(parkRegionId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        //
    }
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong in my code. `Helper.GetHttpClient()` is setting the `HttpClient`. Is the deadlock caused by this line `using (var client = Helper.GetHttpClient())`.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.configureAwait(false)` is usually the right answer - especially in library code

Comment: Deadlock caused by code you did not show - you call `.Wait` or `.Result` somewhere when calling one of those methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation is almost exactly the same as the example provided by Stephen Cleary in his blog: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html . I highly recommend reading it and understanding it, since this is a common issue.

Now the code you showed should not deadlock by itself even without ConfigureAwait(false). My guess is that somewhere up the chain, you're blocking on the async code, and that's causing the deadlock. Stephen outlines two solutions to this problem in his article:

1. In your “library” async methods, use ConfigureAwait(false) wherever possible.
2. Don’t block on Tasks; use async all the way down.

Either one of these will prevent the deadlock, but using both is preferable.